# Cannot able to drag and drop JFXTimePicker control

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder, jfoenix

Recently I downloaded the jfoenix(version 9.0.10) library. It worked fine so far. But when I tried to drag and drop JFXTimePicker in the java scene builder, its not working. I am using the latest version of scene builder and intellij. How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49459941/cannot-use-intellijs-scenebuilder-with-jfoenix Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48841043/importing-jfoenix-library-to-scenebuilder-javafx

Comment: I installed scene builder8.x and jfoenix8.x. But it was not working as I am using java16. I am able to drag controllers but my program is showing error when I run it.

Comment: @swarna  Have you found any solution?  
I am having the same problem with JFXTimePicker and some other jfoenix's components.  :(

Comment: @MohammadHosseinZiyaaddini I have installed Java 8 jdk, and scene builder version 8.x. It works fine with jfoenix 8 jar. I got my JFXTimePicker working

Comment: @swarna Ok, tnx